# Closing AJAX content with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble getting the 'content' div to close when the user clicks on 'span3 a' after opening it.

It fades out and hides the div for a split second. How do i target the span3 a properly in order to close content after being opened?

```
 $(".span3").on('click', 'a', function (e) {
          var href;
          e.preventDefault();
          href = $(this).attr("href");
          $(".team-loop").find("a").removeClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
          $('#staff_expand').fadeOut().hide();
          $(".content").load(href + " #staff_expand");
        });
```

HTML structure:

```
<div class="content border-bottom" >    </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <ul class="team-loop">
                    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'team', 'posts_per_page' => 30 );
                        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                            echo '<li class="span3 mobile_width"><a href="' . get_permalink() .  '">';
                            the_content();
                            echo  '<span class="staff_names"><span class="plus"> + </span>';
                            the_title(); 
                            echo '</span></a></li>';
                        endwhile;
                    ?>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

And then the section being pulled in from url is:

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="staff_expand">
    <div class="span3">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <div><?php echo $title; ?></div>
        <div><?php echo $email; ?></div>
        <div><?php echo $number; ?></div>
        <div><?php echo $linkedin; ?></div>
        <div class="add_to_contacts"><?php echo $addcontact; ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
    <div class="desc"><?php echo $text1; ?></div>
    <div class="desc"><?php echo $text2 ;?></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you let us know the html structure you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".span3").on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".team-loop").find("a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    $('.content').fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(this).load(href + " #staff_expand", function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(400);
        });
    });
});
```